# "System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication4.Models.Book>" не содержит определения для "Id"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Visual Studio 2015

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HomeControllet:

```html
 BookContext db = new BookContext();

        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Books);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

Index.cshtml:

```html
@Model WebApplication4.Models.Book
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Model WebApplication4.Models.Book

<h2>Книга № @Model.Id</h2>

@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

Book ( Model ):

```html
  public class Book
    {
        
        public int Id { get; set; }
      
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public string Author { get; set; }
     
        public int Price { get; set; }


    }
```

BookContext ( Model ) :

```html
 public class BookContext :DbContext
    {
        public BookContext() : base("BookContext")
        { }
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }

    }
```

WebConfig:

```html
    <add name="BookContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Bookstore.mdf;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  </connectionStrings>
```

База данных заполнена данными. В чем проблема ?

Comment: Очевидно в том, что вы в представлении Index  объявляете моделью класс `Book`, а передаёте `DbSet<Book>`. Попробуйте например так: 
`db.Books.First()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    BookContext db = new BookContext ();
    Book singleBook = db.Books.Where( b=> b.ID == "1" ).First();
    return View(singleBook);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Похоже на то что Вы передаете во View коллекцию книг

```
// GET: Home
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Books);
}
```

А во View вы ожидаете одну книгу `Book`, а не коллекцию.